# How to maintain equal x and y length on the NumberAxis in JavaFX LineChart?

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

I am creating a Cartesian Coordinate graph using NumberAxis to create an x and y axis in a LineChart, and use getDisplayPosition to find the distance between two points along the x axis and two points along the y axis. **The differences do not equal each other**.

I set upper/lower bounds of the x and y axis to be the same with the same tickUnit setting.  Visually, the grid looks square and equal on all sides but I cannot seem to make them exactly equal.

Here is how I set NumberAxis for x and y within my linechart:

```
xAxis.setLowerBound(-2.4);
xAxis.setUpperBound(2.4);
xAxis.setTickUnit(.1);
xAxis.setSide(Side.BOTTOM);
xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

yAxis.setLowerBound(-2.4);
yAxis.setUpperBound(2.4);
yAxis.setTickUnit(.1);
yAxis.setSide(Side.LEFT);
yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

LineChart linechart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
```

Here is how I convert inputs for a rectangle to be displayed properly

```
private Rectangle calcRectangle(SectionRectangle rectangle){
        double xPosition = xAxis.getDisplayPosition(rectangle.getXorigin()); 
        double yPosition = yAxis.getDisplayPosition(rectangle.getYorigin());
        double xCoord = xPosition + chartZeroX;//x origin of rectangle 
        double yCoord = yPosition + chartZeroY;//y origin of rectangle

        double width = rectangle.getXorigin() + rectangle.getWidth();

        double widthPosition = xAxis.getDisplayPosition(width);
        double heightPosition = yAxis.getDisplayPosition(rectangle.getYorigin() + rectangle.getHeight());

        Rectangle calculatedRectangle = new Rectangle(xCoord, yCoord - (yPosition - heightPosition), widthPosition - xPosition, yPosition - heightPosition);

        calculatedRectangle.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Rotate rotate = new Rotate();
        rotate.setAngle(360 - rectangle.getRotation());
        rotate.setPivotX(xPosition + chartZeroX);
        rotate.setPivotY(yPosition + chartZeroY);
        calculatedRectangle.getTransforms().add(rotate);
        calculatedRectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        return calculatedRectangle;
```

And here is how I add the shape onto the graph

```
Pane chartContent = (Pane) linechart.lookup(".chart-content");
Rectangle rectangle = calcRectangle(rectangleData);
chartContent.getChildren().add(rectangle);
```

Without rotating, the rectangle will be displayed to scale as expected, but because of the slight variance in pixel width vs pixel height, rotating 90 degrees causes the rectangle to measure taller than it had measured wide.

Here is a more precise example of the issue

```
double xdiff = xAxis.getDisplayPosition(1) - xAxis.getDisplayPosition(0);
double ydiff = yAxis.getDisplayPosition(0) - yAxis.getDisplayPosition(1);
```

here xdiff = 195.208 and ydiff = 191.041

Hoping for some way to force the x and y axis to maintain exact equal distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem by controlling the height and width of the linechart:

```
linegraph.setPrefHeight(850);
linegraph.setMinHeight(850);
linegraph.setMaxHeight(850);
linegraph.setMinWidth(853);
linegraph.setMaxWidth(853);
linegraph.setPrefWidth(853);
linegraph.setPrefSize(853, 850);
linegraph.setMinSize(853, 850);
linegraph.setMaxSize(853, 850);
```

I did a check of the distance between x=0, x=1 and y=0, y=1 using:

```
double xlength = xAxis.getDisplayPosition(1) - xAxis.getDisplayPosition(0);
double ylength = yAxis.getDisplayPosition(0) - yAxis.getDisplayPosition(1);
```

I slowly incremented my width until both lengths were equal.